# iOS Firebase sign in with custom token not working on some devices (Xcode 15)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When login with Firebase it getting following error in some devices.

> Error:- An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

- This app uploaded on App Store Testflight.
- Also app uninstalled then install new app.
- After facing this issue, I verified the GoogleService-Info.plist file. (it is correct)
- Also verified on Firebase console if all services are enabled or not. (services are enabled)
- On server I checked if refreshToken token generate is correct or not. (it is correct)

Following is my code:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: refreshToken) { _, error in
    if let authError = error {
        log.debug(authError.localizedDescription)
        //Error:- An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
        return
    } else {
        self.goToNextStep()
    }
}

//refreshToken = Token generated from server
//refresh Token sample:- eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJmaXJlYmFzZS1hZG1pbnNkay1YWFhAWFhYLVhYWC1YWC5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2Nv
dW50LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vaWRlbnRpdHl0b29sa2l0Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2dv
b2dsZS5pZGVudGl0eS5pZGVudGl0eXRvb2xraXQudjEuSWRlbnRpdHlUb29sa2l0IiwiZXhwIjox
NzAxNzU5MDAwLCJpYXQiOjE3MDE3NTU0MDAsInN1YiI6ImZpcmViYXNlLWFkbWluc2RrLVhYWEBk
WFhYLVhYWC5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInVpZCI6IlhYWFhYWCJ9.SIGNATURE
```

*Some device gets the above error. How i can resolve this issue?*

It perfectly works on my simulators (iPhone 15 (iOS 17), iPhone 15 Pro (iOS 17)).
It perfectly works on my all devices (iPhone XS (iOS 15, iOS 16), iPhone 14 pro (iOS 17)).

I want to fix this issue or trace why this issue is produced.

Comment: Print the error not the localized description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the following is the reason for that issue.

Use "error.debugDescription" to print the full error.

I used "authError.localizedDescription" so it print the following message

> "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."

Then after change code to "error.debugDescription" so it printed following message

```
Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."
.
.
.
code = 403;
details =     (
{
"@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo";
domain = "googleapis.com";
reason = "API_KEY_IP_ADDRESS_BLOCKED";
.
.
.
message = "The provided API key has an IP address restriction. The originating IP address of the call (2402:0000:0000:2450:356f:42g4:5b89:9754) violates this restriction.";
status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
}}}})
```

Then after i allowed my api domain in google console.
previously it was ip address so server side it working but client side it not working.